# How can I replace the 's with ''s for just a column of a dataset using gsub?

Tags: r, csv, apply, lapply, gsub

The Dataset is a csv file with 7 columns and 3872 rows. I want to create an sql query, but the ('s) gives an error during query runtime. That's why I need to replace the ('s) with (''s) to create the query. All help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataset$column <- gsub("'s", '"s', dataset$column)
```

Comment: Please include some details about why you think your solution should work - `'s` replaces any `'s` inside the string with `"s`, even in `'start'`.